# Python Machine Learning Regression P.1 pandas error

Tags: python-3.x

[Pycharm screenshot of error message with code above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9oFTD.png)

I don't know what to do about the error. I don't know what it means

also there should `print(data.head())` between line 8 & 9.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow @thehumanbean. The error you are seeing is telling us that python cannot locate the file you specify in `read.csv()`. To fix this, you need to tell python where to look for this file. There are a few ways. See my answer below for some help. Also, take a look at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to see a general guideline on asking questions.

Answer (score 0):

The error is happening in your `data = read.csv()` line. Check your working directory, or point explicitly to the file location, using something like:

```
data = read.csv("C:/Users/user/filename.csv")
```

Comment: right i will try that. havent done this for a while and am using pycharm instead of the regular idle where i have everything organized differently. thx. edit: putting it the same directery worked and that. thx

Comment: @thehumanbean: glad this helped! And understandable - this isn’t quite the same as bike riding. Easy to lose the syntax after a bit. Please mark as ‘answered’ to close the question for the community. (Check mark)